# Gray UISearchBar w/matching scope bar programmatically

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar, tintcolor

I'm trying to recreate this UISearchBar (as seen in the Table Search example code):

[alt text http://img168.imageshack.us/img168/6378/43558113.png](http://img168.imageshack.us/img168/6378/43558113.png)

All the examples I've seen to do this involve using a xib, however I need to do it programmatically.  The problem is changing the tint color also changes the cancel button's tint:

[alt text http://img243.imageshack.us/img243/1375/screenshot20100527at944.png](http://img243.imageshack.us/img243/1375/screenshot20100527at944.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Associating the search bar with a UISearchDisplayController magically provides a lot of standard look and behavior such as:

- gray tint without affecting cancel button
- auto showing/hiding of cancel button
- width adjustment around any tableview indexes

In my tableview controller I've done the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // setup searchBar and searchDisplayController

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [searchBar sizeToFit];
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

    UISearchDisplayController *searchDC = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];

    // The above assigns self.searchDisplayController, but without retaining.
    // Force the read-only property to be set and retained. 
    [self performSelector:@selector(setSearchDisplayController:) withObject:searchDC];

    searchDC.delegate = self;
    searchDC.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    searchDC.searchResultsDelegate = self;

    [searchBar release];
    [searchDC release];
}
```

Comment: Check also Joris Kluivers answer about overwriting searchDisplayController

Comment: In case anyone is thinking of using this -- my app just got rejected for using non-public APIs. setSearchDisplayController was the culprit.

Answer (score 16):

I totally agree with *Scott McCammon*.

However using a `performSelector:withObject:` on `setSearchDisplayController:` would not be my approach. This depends on private API which can change at any moment. If Apple would remove their private implementation your app will crash.

A better way would be to override the `searchDisplayController:` in your view controller to return your instance of `UISearchDisplayController`:

```
- (UISearchDisplayControlelr *) searchDisplayController {
    return yourInstanceOfASearchController;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the need for the call to `setSearchDisplayController:` or the override for `searchDisplayController`. Under iOS 4.3.2 `initWithSearchBar:contentsController:` appears to set `searchDisplayController` for the `UIViewController` instance passed as the `contentsController` argument. Perhaps this was a problem in earlier iOS releases, but it appears redundant in the current release.

Comment: I did some more testing. searchDisplayController is getting assigned, but not retained as noted by Scott McCammon above. Rather than call the undocumented API, I'm saving a retained reference in an instance variable and then releasing it in dealloc.

Comment: Ditto for me. I use 3 private instance variables on the .m file:     UISearchBar* searchBar;
NSArray* filteredList;
UISearchDisplayController* searchController;.
Under ARC, I don't believe you need to nil them out in a 'dealloc' but I'm no expert. When combining iOS 4 & ARC, you need to nil out weak references, but regular (strong) references are automatically nil'ed out.

Comment: it's apparently best practice to use properties for objects such as UISearchDisplayController let alone most objects in general. In fact, I couldn't get my SDC working unless I declared a property. So I used Scott McCammon's code and instead of locally declaring the SDC I made a private property for it.