# How can I add a UISearchDisplay controller PROGRAMMATICALLY?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I've been searching for this day, but I can't find it....

Could anyone point me to a tutorial/tell me what I should do?
The documentation wasn't really helpful...
I need this for my UITableViewController class (without a xib!)

Thanks A lot!

Comment: Have you seen this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959299/gray-uisearchbar-w-matching-scope-bar-programmatically

Comment: interesting... but: where do I add what should be displayed in the "search table view"? I know the datasource is self... but I don't know what to do further..

Comment: Implement the Search Bar Delegate Methods and when the User types, pick out the matching rows from your old Data Source and create a new one and reload your table with the contents of the new Data Source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First do [Gray UISearchBar w/matching scope bar programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959299/gray-uisearchbar-w-matching-scope-bar-programmatically)

Then since the tableview and the searchtableview both use the same datasource, you have to insert an if statement in the tableview delegate methods like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResutsTableView) {
        tableViewData = searchResultsData objectatindex...; //array with filtered data
    } else {
        tableViewData = defaultData objectatindex...; //array with unfiltered data
    }
}
```

Do the same for the number of rows delegate method:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return searchResultsData.count;
    } else {
        return defaultData.count;
    }
}
```

Then after the search text changes or search button is pressed (look at UISearchBar delegate methods), reload data to display.