# Adding section and index list with custom cell, searchdisplaycontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have created a `UITableView` with custom cell & stored name,no,pincode in to these cell.

Here is my Code for array:-

```
for (int i =0; i<[tempArr count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *rawData = [tempArr objectAtIndex:i];

        if (rawData !=nil)
        {
            Persons *newPerson = [[Persons alloc]init];

            NSArray *data = [rawData componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"];

            newPerson.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[data objectAtIndex:0]];
            newPerson.no = [[data objectAtIndex:1] integerValue];
            newPerson.pincode = [[data objectAtIndex:2] integerValue];

            [allPersons addObject:newPerson];
        }
    }
```

Here is my **Customcell.h**

```
@interface Customcell : UITableViewCell

@property(weak) Persons* person;

@end
```

UITableView Datasrouce method:-

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Customcell *cell = [tblStations dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"personCell"];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        cell.person = filteredContentList[indexPath.row];
        [cell.textLabel setText:cell.person.name];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.person = allPersons[indexPath.row];
        [cell.textLabel setText:cell.person.name];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

How do i create Section & index list for all names from A to Z & give title by cell.textLabel.text?

[I am following This Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/) but it has static keys & names added to `NSDictionary`,`NSArray`.

In my example i do not know how many names starting with same letter can come in the array. i am also using `UISearchDisplayController` for search person name.

I want to add number of sections & title for those sections by names that is in the array or cell.textLabel.text dynamically.

i do not know about UISearchDisplayController that these sections & index list will be displaying in UISearchDisplayController so i do not want these sections & index list while searching.

Comment: Maybe this answer might help solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410353/search-bar-and-search-display-controller-in-table-view/23452670#23452670

Comment: @andrewbuilder no, i have already added search functionality but my array allPersons contains many names with same letters at first like  Andew,Andy,Aerial,Bony,Biska,Vincent,Vonboy,Zed,Zion etc... so i can't  use that array for numberofsections.

I need to give number of sections count that has no duplicate letters in that array which is in allPersons(name).

Comment: To populate your `numberOfSections` custom method, create a separate `NSSet` local variable based on your array and return that value.

Comment: @andrewbuilder but checking for every name in array & creating another dictionary with number of sections sound ridiculous to me because i have to add number of names in the dictionary that starts with letter, e.g. A= 26,B=10,C=5 etc by running for loop for every name & A to Z.

Comment: Read carefully... I suggested you create a set, not a dictionary. Two very different concepts. A set contains only one of each occurrence. So if your array has 26 items that start with the letter A, the corresponding set will contain one letter A.

Comment: Just did, see answer I loaded. Read about `NSSet` in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to spend a little more time trying to make your questions more clear.

Include a custom implementation of the necessary `UITableView` data source and delegate methods...

NOTE my assumption that your variable `allPersons` is an `NSMutableArray`.

NOTE these do not include for your search results data sets!

Return an `NSInteger` for the number of sections in your `UITableView`...

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSSet *setData = nil;
    NSInteger integerData = 0;

    setData = [NSSet setWithArray:allPersons];
    integerData = [setData count];

    return integerData;
}
```

---

UPDATE

Return an `NSString` for section header titles...

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSOrderedSet *setData = nil;
    NSString *stringData = nil;

    setData = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:allPersons];
    stringData = [[setData allObjects] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

    return stringData;      
}
```

...plus others if I have the time...

Comment: i am sorry for making it confusing but i have done as you said but shall i pass this set for titleForHeaderInSection & sectionIndexTitlesForTableView as well, so that i can see title with those unique letters from NSSet & in Indexlist.?

Comment: No. Each needs a separate implementation of the appropriate custom method. You really need to do some more work attempting to understand how a `UITableView` works. There is a lot of information available online. I don't have time to write up all the methods for you now, but may be able to do so later.